# Javascript onkeydown event fire only once?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want  to have a `onkeydown` event fire a function only once. for that function to fire again, the user has to release the key and press/hold again. 
I know its fairly simple but I'm new at JS. Also I prefer to avoid using jQuery or other libs.
One more thing, this should work for both ie and firefox.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could set a flag:

```
var fired = false;

element.onkeydown = function() {
    if(!fired) {
        fired = true;
        // do something
    }
};

element.onkeyup = function() {
    fired = false;
};
```

Or unbind and rebind the event handler (might be better):

```
function keyHandler() {
     this.onkeydown = null;
     // do something
}

element.onkeydown = keyHandler;

element.onkeyup = function() {
    this.onkeydown = keyHandler;
};
```

[More information about "traditional" event handling.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)

You might also want to use `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` to bind the event handlers. For more information about that, have a look at [*quirksmode.org - Advanced event registration models*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Answer (score 42):

I'm surprised it's not mentioned, there's also `event.repeat`:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.repeat) return;

  console.log(e.key);
});
```

This will only fire once per each keypress, since `event.repeat` turns `true` after holding the key down.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#keyboardevent_sequence

Comment: @SebastianBudka why so? I would personally think that performance wise this would be faster if perceivable, not to talk about readability.

Comment: @Adam I am fairly new to frontend world... and honestly I have no idea what I had in mind back than. I probably thought that  `document.addEventListener('keydown', ...)` would be worse than `element.onkeydown`. Fo future generations, I'm deleting my previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

There's a "once" parameter you can use

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Eg:

```
element.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {  
    doSomething()
}, {once: true});
```

It'll remove it as soon as it's been called.

Alternatively you can use `removeEventListener` if it's a named function

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that uses [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener)

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("textBox");
function oneKeyDown(){
    $("body").append("<h1>KeyDown<h1>"); //just to show the keypress
    textBox.removeEventListener('keydown', oneKeyDown, false);
}
function bindKeyDown(){
  textBox.addEventListener('keydown', oneKeyDown, false);
}
textBox.addEventListener('keyup', bindKeyDown, false)   
bindKeyDown();
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/vMGfp/).**

One note, for IE you will need to use [`attachEvent`, `detachEvent`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Comment: You should note that this only works in Webkit and Firefox. IE uses `attachEvent`.

Comment: Got distracted and forgot to mention it.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
test.onkeydown = function() {
    if ( this.className === 'hold' ) { return false; }
    this.className = 'hold';

    // call your function here
};

test.onkeyup = function() {
    this.className = '';
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/xAReL/2/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) will help you.

What it does is, bind the eventHandler to event, and when event occurs, it runs the eventHandler and unbinds it, so that its not fired at next event.

Comment: *i prefer to avoid using jquery or other libs*. And `one` itself does not help. You'd have to rebind the event handler again.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the other answers, there is no 'onkeyfirstdown' or similar event to listen for.

the best solution is to keep track of which keys are already down in a js-object:

```
var keysdown = {};

element.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  if(!(evt.key in keysdown)) {
    keysdown[evt.key] = true;
    // key first pressed
  }
});

element.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  delete keysdown[evt.key];
});
```

this way, you will not be skipping 'keyfirstpressed' events if more than one key is held down.

(many of the other solutions posted here will only fire when no other keys are down).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that will only run the function you pass it when a key is FIRST pressed on the target (eg `window` or some `input` field). If the user wants to trigger a key again, they'll have to release it and press it again.

---

**Vanilla JS**

```js
const onKeyPress = (func, target = window) => {
  // persistent "store" to track what keys are being pressed
  let pressed = {};

  // whenever a keydown event is fired ontarget element
  const onKeyDown = (event) => {
    // if key isn't already pressed, run func
    if (!pressed[event.which])
      func(event);

    // add key to store
    pressed = { ...pressed, [event.which]: true };
  };

  // whenever a keyup event is fired on the window element
  const onKeyUp = (event) => {
    const { [event.which]: id, ...rest } = pressed;
    // remove key from store
    pressed = rest;
  };

  // add listeners
  target.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

  // return a function that can be called to remove listeners
  return () => {
    target.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
  };
};
```

And then to use it:

```js
const removeListener = onKeyPress((event) => console.log(event.which + ' key pressed'))

removeListener(); // when you want to remove listeners later
```

---

**React and React Hooks**

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useCallback } from 'react';

export const useKeyPress = (func, target = window) => {
  // persistent "store" to track what keys are being pressed
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState({});

  // whenever a keydown event is fired ontarget element
  const onKeyDown = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      // if key isn't already pressed, run func
      if (!pressed[event.which])
        func(event);

      // add key to store
      setPressed({ ...pressed, [event.which]: true });
    },
    [func, pressed]
  );

  // whenever a keyup event is fired on the window element
  const onKeyUp = useCallback((event) => {
    // remove key from store
    const { [event.which]: id, ...rest } = pressed;
    setPressed(rest);
  }, [pressed]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // add listeners when component mounts/changes
    target.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

    // cleanup/remove listeners when component unmounts/changes
    return () => {
      target.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
    };
  }, [target, onKeyDown, onKeyUp]);
};
```

And then to use it:

```js
import { useKeyPress } from 'wherever';

useKeyPress((event) => console.log(event.which + ' key pressed'))
```