# Making a key pressed only register once rather than continually

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a game where you must press the left and right arrow keys alternatively to make the character move, the faster you do it, the quicker he runs. I have however ran into a problem whereby the key is being "held down" in a sense so no matter how quick you press the key it still manages to execute it multiple times.

So I am looking for a way to make the key only be pressed once per press rather than updating if you hold down the key.

here is the code for my key capturing and what it executes at the moment (Which is just an update of points and an update of the image used for the character.

```js
KEY_CODES = {
    37: 'left',
    39: 'right',
    40: 'down',
}
KEY_STATUS = {};
for (code in KEY_CODES) {
    KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[code]] = false;
}
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
        e.preventDefault();
        KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = true;
    }
}
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
        e.preventDefault();
        KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = false;
    }
}

function move() {
    movecounter++;
    // Determine if the action is move action
    if (KEY_STATUS.left || KEY_STATUS.right ||
        KEY_STATUS.down || KEY_STATUS.up) {
        // Redraw the canavs background images ready for the new ones to be placed ontop.
        paintCanvas();
        // to have diagonal movement.
        if (KEY_STATUS.left) {
            ctx.drawImage(imageStore.snowWalk, playerPosW, playerPosH);
            snowStand = true;
            score += 10;
        } else if (KEY_STATUS.right) {
            ctx.drawImage(imageStore.snowWalk, playerPosW, playerPosH);
            score += 10;
        } else if (KEY_STATUS.down) {
            ctx.drawImage(imageStore.snowCrouch, playerPosW, playerPosH);
            snowStand = false;
        }

    }
};
```

Hope you understand the problem I am facing, I have tried to explain it as best as I can here.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353254/javascript-onkeydown-event-fire-only-once

Comment: Ah! Now I feel like a fool.. that wasn't coming up when I was searching. Thank you though, that had just the right answer!

Comment: No problem. It's hard to know exactly the right phrase some times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to have a variable outside of the scope of the event listener that tells you if you're pressing the key for the first time:

```
var pressed = false;
```

Then, in the listener, toggle the state of that variable when the key is pressed:

```
.keydown(function() {
   if (pressed) return;
   pressed = true;
}

.keyup(function() {
   pressed = false;
}
```