# On keydown, run a timer only once with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

I'm making a web game and I want to call a timer when the user starts the game.  Basically, how I'm going about it is when one of the WASD keys is hit, start the timer. The problem is, if you hit the keys more than once, it starts the timer each time. I only want to call the function one time.  I was thinking about `clearInterval()`, but that would stop the timer.  Not ideal.

Here's my code. (Fiddle link below)

What I think is supposed to happen is when any key is pressed, it's going to first check if `fired` is equal to `false`.  If it is, set it to `true`.  Then if the W, A, S, or D key is pressed, start the timer.

Then when the key comes back up, set `fired` to false again.

```
var fired = false;
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");

var playerObj = {
    elapsedTime: 0,
    startTimer: function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            playerObj.elapsedTime += 1;
            timer.innerHTML = playerObj.elapsedTime;
        }, 1000);
    }
};

var fired = false;
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var w = e.keyCode == '87',
        a = e.keyCode == '65',
        s = e.keyCode == '83',
        d = e.keyCode == '68';
    if (!fired) {
        fired = true;
        if (w || a || s || d) {
           playerObj.startTimer();
        }
    }
};

document.onkeyup = function () {
     fired = false;
};
```

I referred to [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353254/javascript-onkeydown-event-fire-only-once) answer and tried to use a flag, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5Lj31en/6/)

Comment: Well your code is setting the flag back to false on keyup. Don't do that.

Comment: @nnnnnn I thought that was odd, too.  Just did what that guy said in the question

Comment: In the other question they're worrying about what happens if the user holds the key down. That's not the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Do you want to call `playerObj.startTimer` once per keydown, or once per game?

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo Once per game

Comment: You chose an answer that stops listening to keyboard events, but doesn't that put an end to the game? How are you supposed to play without the keyboard?

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea is to start the timer only if `fired` is `false`.
If you want the timer to start once per game, set `fired` to `true` on the first keydown event and start the timer. On subsequent keydown events, check the value of `fired` and refuse to start the timer.

```js
var fired = false;
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");

var playerObj = {
    elapsedTime: -1,
    update: function () {
      playerObj.elapsedTime += 1;
      timer.innerHTML = playerObj.elapsedTime;
    },
    startTimer: function () {
        playerObj.update();
        setInterval(playerObj.update, 1000);
    }
};

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var w = e.keyCode == '87',
        a = e.keyCode == '65',
        s = e.keyCode == '83',
        d = e.keyCode == '68';
    if (!fired) {
        fired = true;
        if (w || a || s || d) {
           playerObj.startTimer();
        }
    }
};
```

```css
#timer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">-</div>
```

Another approach is to replace the keydown handler after the first keydown event.

```js
var fired = false;
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");

var playerObj = {
    elapsedTime: -1,
    update: function () {
      playerObj.elapsedTime += 1;
      timer.innerHTML = playerObj.elapsedTime;
    },
    startTimer: function () {
        playerObj.update();
        setInterval(playerObj.update, 1000);
    }
};

var keyToString = {
  87: '&uarr;',
  65: '&larr;',
  83: '&darr;',
  68: '&rarr;'
};

function keyHandler(event) {             // Handles all valid keys.
  var display = document.getElementById('display');
  display.innerHTML = keyToString[event.keyCode];
}

document.onkeydown = function (event) {  // Handles the first valid key.
  if (keyToString[event.keyCode] !== undefined) {
    playerObj.startTimer();              // Start the timer.
    document.onkeydown = keyHandler;     // Replace this key handler.
    keyHandler(event);                   // Call the general key handler.
  }
};
```

```css
#timer, #display {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #444;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
#timer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">-</div>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a flag at all for this, all you have to do is set the eventlistener to `null` after the timer starts and then this function will never run again. It's better than the other solutions here because you don't want this function running anymore potentially blocking other events in the UI.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var w = e.keyCode == '87',
        a = e.keyCode == '65',
        s = e.keyCode == '83',
        d = e.keyCode == '68';

    if (w || a || s || d) {
       playerObj.startTimer();
       document.onkeydown = null;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is the best solution!  Clean and simple, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your process to do the following:

**onkeydown**
check w/a/s/d flag, then set flag and start timer

**onkeyup**
if NOT w/a/s/d keys, then set the flag to false

Is essentially what you are trying to do here.  I think that will be the difference, so stop when enter/g/h/etc is hit.

Answer (score 0):

The question was a little unclear, so this may miss the mark.  It starts the timer once per WASD click.

```
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");

var playerObj = {
    elapsedTime: 0,
    startTimer: function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            playerObj.elapsedTime += 1;
            timer.innerHTML = playerObj.elapsedTime;
        }, 1000);
    }
};

// keep track of keys indiividually
var keyPressed = {
    w: false,
    a: false,
    s: false,
    d: false
};

// make it easy to translate keyCodes to key names
var CODES = {
    87: 'w',
    65: 'a',
    83: 's',
    68: 'd'
};

document.onkeydown = function (e) {

    // look up the key
    var keyName = CODES[e.keyCode];

    // if it's one we're interested in and it hasn't been pressed yet
    if (keyName && !keyPressed[keyName]) {
        playerObj.startTimer();

        // mark it as having been pressed
        keyPressed[keyName] = true;
    }
};
```