# Is there there an initial keypress event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to trigger an event when a key is initially pressed.

JavaScript already provides events for pressing a key down and a key going up as is shown in this [demo](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events#test-stand-test-stand) but I can't find an event for when a key is initially pressed down(and not repeatedly triggering afterwards).

Does jQuery or some other library provide this functionality or do I have to implement it myself?

Comment: @ yehia any, doesn't matter

Comment: I'm confused, what does `initial keypress` mean? You know when the key was pressed down, and if no keyup event occured, it's still pressed down ?

Comment: What do you mean by "initial keypress"? Isn't that exactly what `keydown` is?

Comment: @Lelio an event that triggers only once when a key is initially pressed. kind of the opposite of keyup(triggers only once when a key is released)

Comment: @PaulBoon sorry but I don't get what do you mean with initially. You press it and then release it. What else are you supposed to do with the key?

Comment: Is this what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353254/javascript-onkeydown-event-fire-only-once ?

Comment: @PaulBoon it's keydown the opposite to keyup

Comment: @user yup thats it if you post it as an answer i,l accept it

Comment: @Lelio not really keydown keeps firing when a key is pressed down and keyup only fires on the moment a key goes up(doesnt repeat while it's up)