# How do I keep function active after it has been read? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, animation, html

I am making a simple webpage animation with javascript. Here's what I have so far:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
            function checkKey(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                if (e.keyCode == "38") {
                    var ball=document.getElementById("ball");
                    var posup=0;
                    var speedone=setInterval(up, 0);
                    function up(){
                        if(posup==240){
                            clearInterval(speedone);
                        }else{
                            posup++;
                            ball.style.bottom=posup*2+"px";
                        }
                    }
                }else if(e.keyCode=="40"){
                    var ball=document.getElementById("ball");
                    var posdown=0;
                    var speedtwo=setInterval(down, 0);
                    function down(){
                        if(posdown==240){
                            clearInterval(speedtwo);
                        }else{
                            posdown++;
                            ball.style.top=posdown*2+"px";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This code is supposed to make a little white ball move up when the up arrow key is pressed and move down when the down arrow key is pressed. It is able to go up and back down, but after it goes down it can't go back up, it can only replay the downwards animation. I have tried to enclose the entire thing in one big parent function, but it still doesn't work. I think it might be because how javascript is read from top to bottom, so the "up" movement code isn't read a second time. I'd like some help and tips on how to fix this problem and get my program up and running, thanks.

Comment: Are you open to using CSS?

Comment: I would try looking at this answer, may offer some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353254/javascript-onkeydown-event-fire-only-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with JavaScript but with styles You are using.

You are setting both  `ball.style.top` and `ball.style.bottom` and the result is inconsistent location so one coordinate triumphs over the other.

If you replace

```
ball.style.bottom=posup*2+"px"
```

with

```
ball.style.top=480 - posup*2+"px"
```

You should get the result you are expecting.

Comment: Oh I think I get it. So you're saying that they can't work at the same time, and that one of them will always be working instead of the other? And the solution you gave made lots of sense. Thanks