# How do I make a "keydown" event that only works the first time it is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is all of the HTML and the relevant parts of the javascript. The javascript snippet is everything from the top and then I've only showed two "keydown" events otherwise there would be a lot to read through. These two events are labelled "SECTION 1" AND "SECTION 2".

I have several different "keydown" events that add various different HTML content. This web page is designed almost entirely out of javascript simply as a demonstration.

Each time the user presses the relevant key I want the content to be added to the HTML document. Currently the same piece of content can be added an infinite amount of times by simply pressing the same key repeatedly. This is not what I want.

How do I make it so that the event can only be carried out the once?

```js
/* ////////// INTIAL TITLE ////////// */

var initialTitle = document.createElement("h1");
var intialTitleContent = document.createTextNode("Please press the \"1\" key on your keyboard.");
initialTitle.appendChild(intialTitleContent);
document.body.appendChild(initialTitle);

/* ////////// KEYPRESS FUNCTIONS ////////// */

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);
function checkKeyPress(key) {
    
// SECTION 1 - Paragraph explaining what this page is about and what to do.
    if (key.keyCode == "49") // "1"
    {
        var pElement = document.createElement("p");
        var content = document.createTextNode("Welcome! This page is made entirely out of javascript. It is completely impractical to create a webpage in this manner. This page is simply a demonstration of how javascript can be used to create and add HTML element and CSS to a HTML document. Meaning within the HTML document the <body> element only contains a link to the javascript code and what the javascript code has added. You can add content by pressing the \"1\" through to \"9\" keys. Each piece of content can then be styled by pressing the \"s\" key.");
        pElement.appendChild(content);
        document.body.appendChild(pElement);
    }
    
// SECTION 2 - TABLE
    else if (key.keyCode == "50") // "2"
    {
        var tableDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var tableElement = document.createElement("table");

        tableDiv.classList.add("div_1");
        
        for (var z = 1; z <= 4; z++) { //Creating "tr" elements.
            var trElement = document.createElement("tr");
            
            tableElement.appendChild(trElement);
            
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { //Creating "td" elements within the "tr" elements.
                var tdElement = document.createElement("td");

                tdElement.classList.add("tableCell");
                trElement.appendChild(tdElement);
            }
        }
        
        tableDiv.appendChild(tableElement);
        document.body.appendChild(tableDiv); 
        
        /* Table styling below this point */
        
        var tableCellStyling = document.getElementsByClassName("tableCell");
        
        for (var y = 0; y < tableCellStyling.length; y++) {
            tableCellStyling[y].style.width = "80px";
            tableCellStyling[y].style.height = "80px";
            tableCellStyling[y].style.border = "2px solid #303030";
        }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale= 1.0"/>
    <title>Javascript Only Site</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="js/JOS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use boolean flags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript onkeydown event fire only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353254/javascript-onkeydown-event-fire-only-once)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want an event to be only ever fired once, you would `removeEventListener` inside the callback for the event. You will need a variable which contains a reference to the handler to do this, so it would look like:

```js
var eventHandler = function(event){
  //do things
  document.removeEventListener('keypress', eventHandler);
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', eventHandler);
```

But looking at your snippet, if you wanted to only fire each keycode behavior once, you could create a map which tracks which keys have been previously been pressed and then short return.

```js
var pressedKeys = {};

/* ////////// INTIAL TITLE ////////// */

var initialTitle = document.createElement("h1");
var intialTitleContent = document.createTextNode("Please press the \"1\" key on your keyboard.");
initialTitle.appendChild(intialTitleContent);
document.body.appendChild(initialTitle);

/* ////////// KEYPRESS FUNCTIONS ////////// */

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);
function checkKeyPress(key) {



    /** ADDED CODE **/
    if(pressedKeys[key.keyCode] !== undefined){//return if we've seen this key before
      return;
    }
    pressedKeys[key.keyCode] = 1;//just assign a value
    /** END ADDED CODE **/
    
    
    
    
// SECTION 1 - Paragraph explaining what this page is about and what to do.
    if (key.keyCode == "49") // "1"
    {
        var pElement = document.createElement("p");
        var content = document.createTextNode("Welcome! This page is made entirely out of javascript. It is completely impractical to create a webpage in this manner. This page is simply a demonstration of how javascript can be used to create and add HTML element and CSS to a HTML document. Meaning within the HTML document the <body> element only contains a link to the javascript code and what the javascript code has added. You can add content by pressing the \"1\" through to \"9\" keys. Each piece of content can then be styled by pressing the \"s\" key.");
        pElement.appendChild(content);
        document.body.appendChild(pElement);
    }
    
// SECTION 2 - TABLE
    else if (key.keyCode == "50") // "2"
    {
        var tableDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var tableElement = document.createElement("table");

        tableDiv.classList.add("div_1");
        
        for (var z = 1; z <= 4; z++) { //Creating "tr" elements.
            var trElement = document.createElement("tr");
            
            tableElement.appendChild(trElement);
            
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { //Creating "td" elements within the "tr" elements.
                var tdElement = document.createElement("td");

                tdElement.classList.add("tableCell");
                trElement.appendChild(tdElement);
            }
        }
        
        tableDiv.appendChild(tableElement);
        document.body.appendChild(tableDiv); 
        
        /* Table styling below this point */
        
        var tableCellStyling = document.getElementsByClassName("tableCell");
        
        for (var y = 0; y < tableCellStyling.length; y++) {
            tableCellStyling[y].style.width = "80px";
            tableCellStyling[y].style.height = "80px";
            tableCellStyling[y].style.border = "2px solid #303030";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm sure you're right but I still can't get this to work. "pressedKeys" is flagged as undefined which might be the problem. Your code is currently making it so no keypress events work. I'm a bit confused. Can you offer any more advice?

Answer (score 2):

Declare a boolean at the top of your script:

```
let keyDownAllowed = true;
```

Then inside your keydown event:

```
if(keyDownAllowed){
   //Set keyDownAllowed to false;
   keyDownAllowed = false;
   //Add to your HTML
}else{
   //Just return or do anything else which you want to do on every key down
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You remove the event listener after the first time the event fires.

```js
document.querySelector('input').onkeydown = () => {
  alert('key down')
  document.querySelector('input').onkeydown = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.removeEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);
```

You can use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) to remove the listener at any time. function reference and useCapture flag should be same though.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);

function checkKeyPress(e) {
  alert(e.key + ' pressed');
  window.removeEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);
}

window.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not *quite* what the question is asking, I suspect that many people stumbling across this post are looking for a way to only capture the first of the multiple `keydown` events that are rapidly triggered in succession by a browser/OS when a key is held down.

Here is my solution that will only run the function you pass it when a key is FIRST pressed on the target (eg `window` or some `input` field). If the user wants to trigger a key again, they'll have to release it and press it again.

---

**Vanilla JS**

```js
const onKeyPress = (func, target = window) => {
  // persistent "store" to track what keys are being pressed
  let pressed = {};

  // whenever a keydown event is fired ontarget element
  const onKeyDown = (event) => {
    // if key isn't already pressed, run func
    if (!pressed[event.which])
      func(event);

    // add key to store
    pressed = { ...pressed, [event.which]: true };
  };

  // whenever a keyup event is fired on the window element
  const onKeyUp = (event) => {
    const { [event.which]: id, ...rest } = pressed;
    // remove key from store
    pressed = rest;
  };

  // add listeners
  target.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

  // return a function that can be called to remove listeners
  return () => {
    target.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
  };
};
```

And then to use it:

```js
const removeListener = onKeyPress((event) => console.log(event.which + ' key pressed'))

removeListener(); // when you want to remove listeners later
```

---

**React and React Hooks**

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useCallback } from 'react';

export const useKeyPress = (func, target = window) => {
  // persistent "store" to track what keys are being pressed
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState({});

  // whenever a keydown event is fired ontarget element
  const onKeyDown = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      // if key isn't already pressed, run func
      if (!pressed[event.which])
        func(event);

      // add key to store
      setPressed({ ...pressed, [event.which]: true });
    },
    [func, pressed]
  );

  // whenever a keyup event is fired on the window element
  const onKeyUp = useCallback((event) => {
    // remove key from store
    const { [event.which]: id, ...rest } = pressed;
    setPressed(rest);
  }, [pressed]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // add listeners when component mounts/changes
    target.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

    // cleanup/remove listeners when component unmounts/changes
    return () => {
      target.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
    };
  }, [target, onKeyDown, onKeyUp]);
};
```

And then to use it:

```js
import { useKeyPress } from 'wherever';

useKeyPress((event) => console.log(event.which + ' key pressed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. If you want to track few keys holded simultanously and do an action when specific combination is pressed try this. Check a console for results. Requires jQuery.

```
var key_statuses = {};

$(function () {
    $('body').keydown(function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (key_statuses[code] == "down") {
            return;
        }
        key_statuses[code] = "down";

        // Your actions here

        console.clear();
        console.log(key_statuses);
    });

    $('body').keyup(function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        delete key_statuses[code];

        console.clear();
        console.log(key_statuses);
    });
});
```