# How to make a key fire only once when pressed?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I'm making a simple JavaScript game <s>(Space Invaders style)</s> (Top-down space shooter) and I'm trying to make my character shoot a bullet per each 'space' key press. How can I do that?

I have tried multiple approaches, setting a flag, using onkeypress instead of keydown, Google searches (have also encountered this similar question yet it didn't help: [Javascript onkeydown event fire only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353254/javascript-onkeydown-event-fire-only-once))

Below is an example of one solution I have tried.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) 
{
      if(e.keyCode == 32 && space == false)
      {
           space = true;         
      }
}

document.onkeyup = function(e)
{
     if(e.keyCode == 32) space = false;
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

function gameLoop(timeStamp) 
{      if(space === true)
       {   
          p.shoot();
       }

       window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

Expected results: Key being fired only once.
Actual results: Key is being fired multiple times.

Comment: You can't prevent key events fire multiple times, but you can check if the key is [repeated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat).

Comment: You can't really expect this event to be fired once per key. You have to wrap it up with logic that will let it pass through only once per key. If this is what you want, I'll post an answer about it.

Comment: the code is not really showing enough to help you

Comment: I'm guessing your code that "fires the bullet" just checks the state of `space` ... in a loop ... so fires off a bullet every iteration ... in space invaders, you can only fire one bullet at a time ... so `space = false` needs to be done when the bullet "expires" and you need some other logic that says "there's already a bullet, so don't make a new one"

Comment: I'll be glad if you could post an answer where this event will fire once per keypress. I'll also edit this question and show more lines of my code.

Comment: @Kfir It is not possible, but as I said in the previous comment, you can detect if the key was repeated. Put `if (e.repeat) return;` as the first line in the keydown handler function, and don't use keyup handler at all (in case you don't need that for something else).

Comment: your update confirmed my suspicion ... your animation loop will fire a bullet every iteration until the space key is released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really 3 states to a bullet - and, taking into consideration that in classic Space Invaders the player can only have one bullet in flight at a time, this makes things relatively simple

The bullet can be

- NONE - doesn't exist
- FIRED - i.e. need to create one
- EXISTS - it's in flight

The code to handle it is relatively simple too

```
var BulletState = {
    NONE: 0,
    FIRED: 1,
    EXISTS: 2
};
var bullet = BulletState.NONE;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && bullet === BulletState.NONE) {
        bullet = BulletState.FIRED;
    }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);


function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
    if (bullet === BulletState.FIRED) {
        bullet = BulletState.EXISTS;
        p.shoot(); // p.shoot needs to set bullet = BulletState.NONE when the bullet expires
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

document.onkeyup = function(e)
{
     // not required at all
}
```

> edit: To fire a bullet every press of spacebar (allowing multiple bullets)

```
var space = false;
var fireBullet = 0;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && !e.repeat && !space) {
        fireBullet++;
        space = true;
    }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);


function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
    while (fireBullet) {
        p.shoot();
        fireBullet--;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

document.onkeyup = function(e)
{
    space = false;
}
```

I use fireBullet++ and fireBullet-- because I guess it's plausible that someone could press and release and press the spacebar within 16ms (single frame) :p

You could also do

```
function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
    if (fireBullet) {
        p.shoot();
        fireBullet--;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

that way you still handle multiple bullets OK, but only fire off one per frame - really depends on how you want to handle someone with a very fast trigger finger :p

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. My intention in this specific game that I'm making is to allow the players to shoot as many bullets as they want (there can be multiple bullets in flight in any given time) depending on how fast they are pressing the 'space' key.

Comment: oh, OK, I thought you said Space Invaders :p let me rewrite that

Comment: No worries! It was my fault. I've edited my question so it's more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

As [@JaromandaX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) suggested, `space = false;` after `p.shoot();` will give you the desired result:

Reproducing the issue:

```js
var space = false;
var element = document.querySelector('input');

element.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (!space && e.keyCode == 32) {
    space = true;
    console.log('event fired');
  }
};

element.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32)
    space = false;
}


window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
  if (space == true) {
    console.log('shoot');
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

```html
<input />
```

EDIT: Added another `isShot` variable to keep track of shot fired and space key is down in `requestAnimationFrame` event:

```js
var space = false;
var element = document.querySelector('input');
var isShot = false;

element.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (!space && e.keyCode == 32) {
    space = true;
    console.log('event fired');
  }
};

element.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
     space = isShot = false;
  }
}


window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
  if (space && !isShot) {
    console.log('shoot');
    isShot = true;
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: not necessarily, because p.shoot is not synchronous and the bullet will take multiple frames to "expire" - so just setting `space = false` at that point is not going to help

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my issue. If I hold down the 'space' key, it will fire one bullet single and then fire more repeatedly.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have two event, on each key press three are three even that get's fired 
 1. `keydown` (when user press the key but not yet release the key)
 2. `keypress` (its fired after the keydown event)
 3. `keyup` (When user release the key)
If you want to fire only once for each keypress
implement on of those if implement all of the three all three methods will fired.
Additionally: for safety you can write `e.preventDefault()`.