# How to limit a keyboard event to only allow one repetition after user input?

Tags: javascript, foreach, decimal, limit, addeventlistener

Forgive me if my question etiquette is lacking. This is my first calculator from scratch using HTML, CSS, and JS. I am having trouble preventing the application from entering more than one decimal point upon user input.

I have click event listeners 'foreach' button as well as key event listeners on the window.

I have tried a few different methods. I read on stackoverwflow of ways to limit the interactivity to one click - i.e. using "onclick", or testing if the display innerText/textContent .includes('.') and negating that to prevent further decimals from being entered.

I will include all of my code below. I am open to all suggestions. I am a complete novice who started in December and I appreciate any assistance you all may choose to offer. I understand that there may be quite a bit needing streamlining in my code, but this is my only issue right now. Thanks in advance.

```js
// ***** VARIABLE DECLARATIONS AND QUERY SELECTORS ***** //

let displayValue = "";
let displayValue2 = "";
let currentOperator = "";
let currentSolution = "";
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'));
const now = new Date();
const min = now.getMinutes();
const hour = now.getHours();
const hours = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1)
const info = document.querySelector('.infoPane');
const info2 = document.querySelector('.infoPane2');
const inputReadout = document.querySelector('.inputReadout');


// *****MATHEMATICAL FUNCTIONS***** //
function add(...args) {
  return Number((args.reduce((total, current) => total + current, 0)).toFixed(3));
};

function subtract(num1, ...args) {
  return Number((args.reduce((total, current) => total - current, num1)).toFixed(3));
};

function multiply(...args) {
  return Number((args.reduce((incrementer, next) => incrementer * next, 1)).toFixed(3));
};

function divide(num1, ...args) {
  return Number((args.reduce((incrementer, next) => incrementer / next, num1)).toFixed(3));
};



// ***** CALCULATOR OPERATIONAL FUNCTIONS ***** //


//the function below performs a chosen operation on input parameters
function operate(operator, ...args) {

  if (operator === '+' || operator === add) {
    return add(...args);
  } else if (operator === '-' || operator === subtract) {
    return subtract(...args);
  } else if (operator === '*' || operator === multiply) {
    return multiply(...args);
  } else if (operator === '/' || operator === divide || operator === '÷') {
    if (divide(...args) === "Infinity" || divide(...args) === "-Infinity") {
      return "You can't do that...";
    } else {
      return divide(...args);
    }
  } else {
    return "Error - Press AC"
  }
}


//the function below adds user button input to calculator display
function addToDisplay(chars) {
  display.innerText += `${chars}`;

}

//the function below clears the display
function clearDisplay() {
  display.innerText = "";
}

//the function below clears the display value
function clearDisplayValue() {
  displayValue = "";
  displayValue2 = "";

}
//the function below clears the current solution
function clearSolution() {
  currentSolution = "";
}

//the function below toggles positive and negative values
function backspace() {
  display.textContent = (display.textContent).toString().slice(0, -1)
  display.innerText = display.textContent;
}
//the function below changes the result to a percent

function clearDis(input) {
  clearDisplay();
}

//the function below checks if a value is stored. If so, a second value is stored

function valueStatus() {

  if (currentSolution !== "") {
    displayValue = currentSolution;
    displayValue2 = "";
    clearDisplay();
    clearSolution();
  } else if (displayValue === "") {
    displayValue += display.innerText;
    clearDisplay();
  } else if (displayValue2 === "") {
    displayValue2 += display.innerText;
    clearDisplay();
  }
}

//the function below calculates a solution and adds the ability for operator buttons to display totals

function calculate() {
  if (displayValue && displayValue2) {
    currentSolution = operate(currentOperator, Number(displayValue), Number(displayValue2))
  }
  if (currentSolution != 0) {
    display.innerText = currentSolution;
  }
}


function reCalculate() {
  if (displayValue && displayValue2 && currentSolution) {
    valueStatus();
    calculate();
  }
}


//***** EVENT LISTENERS AND FUNCTION CALLS ***** //
buttons.forEach((button) => {



  if (button.className == "allClear") {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      clearDisplay();
      clearDisplayValue();
      clearSolution();
    });
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'a' || event.key === 'A') {
        clearDisplay();
        clearDisplayValue();
        clearSolution();
      }
    });

  } else if (button.className == "backspace") {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      backspace();
    });
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Backspace") {
        backspace();
      }
    });
  } else if (button.className == "clearDis") {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      clearDis(display.innerText);
    });
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'c' || event.key === 'C') {
        clearDis(display.innerText);
      }
    });
  } else if (button.className == "divide") {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      valueStatus();
      calculate();
      currentOperator = divide
      reCalculate();
    });
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
      if (event.key === '÷' || event.key === '/') {
        valueStatus();
        calculate();
        currentOperator = divide
        reCalculate();
      }
    });
  } else if (button.className == "multiply") {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      valueStatus();
      calculate();
      currentOperator = multiply;
      reCalculate();
    });
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'x' || event.key === 'X' || event.key === '*') {
        valueStatus();
        calculate();
        currentOperator = multiply;
        reCalculate();
      }
    });
  } else if (button.className == "subtract") {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      valueStatus();
      calculate();
      currentOperator = subtract;
      reCalculate();
    });
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
      if (event.key === '-') {
        valueStatus();
        calculate();
        currentOperator = subtract;
        reCalculate();
      }
    });
  } else if (button.className == "add") {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      valueStatus();
      calculate();
      currentOperator = add;
      reCalculate();
    });
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
      if (event.key === '+') {
        valueStatus();
        calculate();
        currentOperator = add;
        reCalculate();
      }
    });
  } else if (button.className == "equals") {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      valueStatus();
      calculate();
    });
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
      if (event.key === '=' || event.key === 'Enter') {
        valueStatus();
        calculate();
      }
    });
  } else if (!display.textContent.includes(".") && button.className == "decimal") {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      addToDisplay(button.innerText);
    });
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.key === '.') {
        addToDisplay(button.innerText);
      }
    });
  } else {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      addToDisplay(button.innerText);
    });
  }
});

window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  if (event.key === '1' || event.key === '2' || event.key === '3' || event.key === '4' || event.key === '5' || event.key === '6' || event.key === '7' || event.key === '8' || event.key === '9' || event.key === '0') {
    display.innerText += event.key;
  }
});

info.innerText = `${hours}:${min} ◃ `;
info2.innerText = `  Wi-Fi `;
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

header {
  font-size: 4vmax;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8vmax;
  text-shadow: .4vmax .4vmax 1vmax darkgray;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 2.5vmax;
  box-shadow: .5vmax .5vmax 1vmax 2vmax silver;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33vmax;
  height: 62vmax;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 2.5vmax;
  box-shadow: .5vmax .5vmax #363131;
  padding-bottom: 3vmax;
}

.infoContainer {
  height: 20vmax;
  width: 30vmax;
  display: flex;
}

.infoPane {
  width: 15vmax;
  height: 2vmax;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  font-size: 1.2vmax;
  border-radius: 2.5vmax;
  padding-top: 1.5vmax;
}

.infoPane2 {
  width: 15vmax;
  height: 2vmax;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 1.2vmax;
  border-radius: 2.5vmax;
  padding-top: 1.5vmax;
}

.inputReadout {
  width: 30vmax;
  height: 5vmax;
  font-size: 2.5vmax;
  color: white;
}

.display {
  height: 20vmax;
  width: 30vmax;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 6.5vmax;
}

.buttons {
  position: relative;
  width: 32vmax;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: .6vmax;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  border: solid black;
  border-radius: 35px;
  height: 7vmax;
  width: 7vmax;
  font-size: 2.8vmax;
  text-align: center;
}

.zero {
  width: 14vmax;
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.four,
.five,
.six,
.seven,
.eight,
.nine,
.zero,
.decimal {
  background-color: #5B5B5B;
  color: white;
}

.divide,
.multiply,
.subtract,
.add,
.equals {
  background-color: #FFA811;
  color: white;
}

.allClear,
.backspace,
.clearDis {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.whitebar {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  width: 11vmax;
  border: solid .2vmax white;
  border-radius: 5vmax;
  top: 2.2vmax;
}

.backspace {
  font-size: 1.7vmax;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header> Fruity Phone <br> Calculator </header>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='calculator'>
      <div class='infoContainer'>
        <div class='infoPane'> </div>
        <div class='infoPane2'> </div>
      </div>
      <div class='inputReadout'> </div>
      <div class='display'> </div>
      <div class='buttons'>
        <button class='allClear'> AC </button>
        <button class='clearDis'> C </button>
        <button class='backspace'> Delete </button>
        <button class='divide'> ÷ </button>
        <button class='seven'> 7 </button>
        <button class='eight'> 8 </button>
        <button class='nine'> 9 </button>
        <button class='multiply'> x </button>
        <button class='four'> 4 </button>
        <button class='five'> 5 </button>
        <button class='six'> 6 </button>
        <button class='subtract'> - </button>
        <button class='one'> 1 </button>
        <button class='two'> 2 </button>
        <button class='three'> 3 </button>
        <button class='add'> + </button>
        <button class='zero'> 0 </button>
        <button class='decimal'> . </button>
        <button class='equals'> = </button>
      </div>
      <div class='whitebar'></div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353254/javascript-onkeydown-event-fire-only-once

Comment: Thank you! This put me on the right track. After creating keyFired and clickFired booleans and writing a function to test the display values I was able to get it functioning! Updated code and preview at https://neelvora.github.io/calculator/ - Thanks again!